# Why is the logout button hidden?

Tags: discussion

Why does logging out of Stack Overflow require three clicks? Can’t we just have a link on the navigation bar itself like most websites would do?

As a web developer, I am curious about this.

Comment: It's not hidden, its under StackExchange options.

Comment: You know, funny thing, I never noticed the logout button was tucked under there. Probably because I never log out, and I wonder if this is common among many or most Stackoverflowers.

Comment: it was a question later I found out it's tucked under there! :) @PaulRichter

Comment: Two clicks for any logout is min really, "1 - logout link" and "2 - are you sure" to avoid accidental clicks. So, is one more really so hard? We could argue there could be many frequently used things on the top nav bar, but then it ends up being polluted. Besides, how many times a day is that "one click"?

Comment: @James Presently there isn't a lot on the navigation bar :) But you know , I guess the location of the login link is a design decision. Just want to know what is the rationale behind it. May be there are some stackoverflow developers in this forum who can throw light on this.

Comment: I'm sure they have reasons, as far as I can see, it's tidy there, yet also easy to find

Comment: You can log out?

Comment: There isn't a lot on the navigation bar on purpose.  The location makes sense; any account-changing actions you take are under that menu (or could also be undertaken from the profile I guess).

Comment: I know it is a bad parallel, but many desktop applications require at least 3 clicks to exit.... (1) File Menu (2) Exit (3) Do you want to save?

Comment: @MartinJames any time you like... but you can never leave.

Comment: It's much easier to log out from the iPad app, i've accidentally hit that a few times. Luckily it has a warning.

Comment: Because we don't want you to leave :)

Comment: @nicael: I knew it was a conspiracy.. :-)

Comment: Why would you **ever** want to log out?

Comment: ♪ You can log out any time you like, but you can never leave. ♪

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Our "log out" functionality used to be hidden on the user profile page, so the current location is actually an improvement.  Preliminary designs *did* have the "log out" link in the top bar next to "help". But as we added more items (including "review" and "mod" for some users) it became harder to justify the location. People have [different expectations of what "logging out" means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108161/1438), so depending on what you expect, the link can have surprising results.

I also looked around at some sites I happened to have open at the time and discovered that having a one-click logout button was actually less common than we thought:

[image: Facebook] [image: WordPress]

[image: Dropcam][image: LA Times]

In an internal email, I wrote:

> I didn't cherry pick these sites: FogBugz, Expensify, and the New York Times were the only sites in my recent history that did *not* hide the sign out link.  Top bar, direct links to "log out" are (if my sample is representative) an outdated design element. The sites that hide "log out" are not scummy sites. Rather they are sites that have lots of data to display in the top bar and don't want to waste space on a link that few people intend to use.

Comment: You don't have a Wikipedia account? Shame on you!

Comment: I understand of course, that you don't need rep because of symbol, but it would be good to finally have 10k :)

Comment: "... since logging out includes every site on the network." I thought each stack had its own log out button, and they were independent actions. Or you meant that?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I did some testing and it seems you are correct. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Sumurai8: I do, but I'm rarely logged into it. (Which might be because it's so easy to log out of. I didn't say my test was scientific!)

Answer (score 12):

They follow the design principle that you should make actions that you don't want your users to do, ***harder to do***. So it takes 3 clicks for most people to log out, instead of 1 easy click to log out.

For example, they also do this with closing questions in the review queue. Leave open is only 1 click, but to close vote, it's 2, 3, or 4 clicks depending on close reason.

Comment: While that _is_ a good design principle, it [isn't the one we used](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274716/1438). (And likely has little to do with how many clicks it takes to open or close questions either.)

Comment: "make actions that you don't want your users to do, harder to do" i was thinking on these lines initially before jon ericosn's answer

Comment: @lostsock That's very circumstantial. This just as easily can be based on the principle ***make actions that few users want to do, less conspicuous***. This principle is the also evident in the email quote from Jon Ericsson's answer about *sites that have lots of data to display in the top bar and don't want to waste space on a link that few people intend to use*.

Comment: It should be noted that for vital functions like logout this isn't the best design pattern. I have done it myself, to complaints from customers on retail sites. Apparently it is one of the biggest complaints on Amazon.